# Eliminate meta rep

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

I love my meta rep. I'm shamelessly farming it to help launch the GIS site.

Still, I think that the decision to avoid distinct meta rep on the new sites is a **really smart thing**.

In my opinion, things would be better if your effective rep on meta was derived in some fashion from your rep on the other sites, and that no new rep was created here -- just as on the new sites.

If you read this and agree, please upvote. In the short term, you'll help launch GIS. In the long term, you'll make unicorns smile.

Comment: I'm confused on how you can use your meta rep here to help launch GIS.  What kind of hack is that?

Comment: @Lance The weight of your commitment is based on how much rep on other sites you have. Having 4k+ meta rep contributes towards that.

Comment: @Kyle, thanks, forgot about that.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is a good trick:  by asking people to upvote this, you get more meta rep!

Comment: @Lan meta rep is part of aggregate rep that contributes to launch. Isn't it? If not, I'll just delete this.

Comment: @waf Well, there's Evan Carroll.

Comment: @Ros, yep, you're right, just forgot about that aspect.

Comment: What is this jizz site you're talking about?

Answer (score 12):

You can take my 5 Necromancer badges from my cold dead hand.

Comment: How about from your other one?

Comment: Whose cold dead hand are we taking the badge from?  You *are* a necromancer, after all....

Answer (score 6):

I disagree, because meta.stackoverflow.com is fundamentally different from meta.foo.stackexchange.com.  This meta site has spent a lot of time and discussion on shaping the form of the StackExchange engine as a whole.  The new meta sites don't have to discuss the engine as much, because it is already well-established.  They can devote themselves to issues of moderation that is only relevant to one specific site.

This comes back to the debate as to whether meta.stackoverflow.com will be merged with meta.stackexchange.com. To do this properly we'd need to separate the Stack Overflow-*specific* discussions from those that pertain to the Stack Exchange engine.  No, I'm not volunteering! :)

Comment: Chacun a son goat.

Comment: I think you mean *à chacun son goût*?  But then, Canadian French is akin to Texan English :)

Comment: I choose my jokes capriciously.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [when meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange are split up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124015/188688), then SO and MSO will likely become linked, whereas [the current MSO rep will me moved to the new MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124083/188688).

Comment: Is the post still turned in a comment if you edit the answer after posting it?

Comment: @RobW: It seems that after writing a long enough answer, I can trim it to turn it into a shorter post without it becoming auto-converted to a comment. Ugly hack, but it works.