# Stop special-casing Stack Overflow's meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, meta, per-site-meta

Questions about why Stack Overflow does not share rep with Meta Stack Overflow are met with the response that meta.stackoverflow and stackoverflow do not share a "parent-child relationship" like the other meta sites. For example, [this response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73812/isnt-it-about-time-that-meta-stackoverflow-shared-rep-with-its-parent-just-like/73815#73815):

> Stack Overflow isn't in a parent-child relationship with Meta Stack Overflow like the other sites are with their respective sites. Meta Stack Overflow is intended to handle not only issues with Stack Overflow, but for the Stack Exchange Network as a whole. It is also the specific place to ask questions about Data Explorer, Area 51, and Careers which otherwise lack their own meta sites and even reputation in some cases. In essence - Meta Stack Overflow is the site for all of the Stack Exchange Network. Tying reputation to Stack Overflow would undermine that, since not everyone who knows the engine is particularly active on Stack Overflow.

This just raises the question: *Why* doesn't Stack Overflow have a "real" meta (with a "parent-child" relationship) like the other Stack Exchange sites? *Why* is it treated as a special case? The closest thing I've seen to an explanation is this bit from the [New Per-Site Metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) blog post:

> For now we are leaving meta.stackoverflow.com grandfathered in, as-is, with no changes; it’s still a standalone community with a standalone reputation system. We think Stack Overflow is large enough to justify this, and it just so happens that Stack Overflow is also the name of the company, too. Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.

But this is a really unsatisfying explanation as it doesn't really stand up to reason. How does the fact that Stack Overflow is large justify the lack of a "real" meta site? If anything, shouldn't the fact that it's large actually mean the opposite: that its meta should *not* have some purpose?

### Update

Despite all of the negativity towards this suggestion, it looks like it actually got implemented: [Announcing The Launch Of Meta Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/)

Comment: I don't understand why, if you quote the official blog where they listed their reasons, you are still confused. I could _maybe_ understand if you had never seen the blog, but still. As it is, I think you're just being silly now. You already posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73812/ which was nearly identical in complaint to this one. I don't know what it is you hope to prove, but you seem to be making the same argument time and again. It is what the owners decide it to be. Where's the problem with that? Can I come redecorate your living room to suit my occasional taste?

Comment: @drachenstern as I pointed out, the reason mentioned on the blog is nonsensical. Stack Overflow is large so it shouldn't have a real meta? That makes even less sense than saying it doesn't have a meta because tomatoes are a fruit not a vegetable.

Comment: I have this idea about your living room ... I think the couches would look _lovely_ over by the grill outside. And I think the TV should be next to the pool. Can I come over and rearrange after work tomorrow?

Comment: I would like to reiterate my comment:  **Please don't steal my pretty reputation points!!!!**

Comment: @drachenstern You're basically saying that Stack Overflow et al should not be criticized. First, isn't that part of the reason behind the meta sites: to provide constructive criticism so that they can get better? Second, if you want to know why I've placed my furniture where I've placed it I can give you reasons, and I'm willing to listen to logical arguments for repositioning them. The thing with the no rep sharing on Meta hasn't been given a logical reason. There are two reasons given, one which is completely nonsensical and the other which verges on irrelevant.

Comment: I'm wondering why this matters to you.

Comment: @JJnguy First, merging the rep between both sites would only increase your rep on both sites, never decrease it (though it's possible it would stay the same if you're consistently hitting rep caps). Your comment does sort of reveal the real reason these sorts of questions get down-voted though: all of the Meta people don't want the plebes from Stack Overflow to get higher rep on Meta.

Comment: Actually no. If I put my couch somewhere, I don't expect strangers to tell me where to move it to. Now my wife, on the other hand, can tell me all day long, and I'll have to provide a reason to her. We two can discuss couch placement. We two are like SOIS in this case. You are the stranger. You have no business to demand that the sites be joined or split, nor to tell my wife and I where to put our couch. PS: "demand" :: "Stop special cashing stack overflows meta" <-- reads like a demand to me.

Comment: Please don't judge the entire community based on the votes and joking statements of singular individuals. Second, technically no, merging would not do that - per-site-metas do *not* earn any reputation. The only reputation that would matter would be the Stack Overflow reputation.

Comment: @Laurence, my Meta rep will most definitely go up.  But, I will also lose my spot on the front page.  Turning this meta into a normal meta will mean removing all rep from meta, and making your meta rep your SO rep.

Comment: @JJnguy Because I have a fairly high rep on Stack Overflow, but so little rep on Meta that there are many things I can't do. It seems pretty broken that I can be among the top .2% of Stack Overflow users by rep and yet I'm still locked out of many features on Meta.

Comment: @Laurence: humor aside, JJnguy asks the key question: what *can't* you do on Meta that you can do on SO, and why do you want to do it? Insulting comments about some rep-based class system are irrelevant - if your system were implemented, you would still find yourself facing a large number of users with significantly larger meaningless numbers next to their names than you have next to your own.

Comment: @Laurence, also, many people here contributed before there were metas for specific sites, and are not active on SO.  They will lose privileges that they have earned through hard work on this meta.

Comment: @drachenstern Perhaps you missed the "feature-request" tag. In my experience feature requests are typically stated as imperatives not as questions. I'd also tell you that your inability to accept constructive criticism form strangers suggests that you may have trouble separating your emotions from rational thought processes, but you might take it the wrong way so I'll just keep it to myself.

Comment: @Laurence, I see your point.  Many people would feel however that a reputation on Stack Overflow would not necessarily mean that you should have privs on meta.  (I feel your plight though, and might support a feature request that gave SO privs to people on meta without mashing the reputation system.)

Comment: @Laurence Why didn't you just lead off with "it seems broken that I have 20k rep on SO but can't do much on meta"? It took an hour and dozens of comments to coax out the real reason for this post... Something that alters privileges based on total SE rep isn't a bad idea, since this is the network-wide meta

Comment: And you think I'm the one acting childish? ZOMG!

Comment: @Laurence "It seems pretty broken that I can be among the top .2% of Stack Overflow users by rep and yet I'm still locked out of many features on Meta" - meta.stackoverflow.com serves a dual purpose, and in fact I would characterize it as primarily a StackOverflow LLC site dedicated to perfecting the company's main product than I would characterize it as merely the SO meta site.  However, if you need to be able to access the higher functions of the site, it is astonishingly easy to get rep here. If you still have problems, flag posts and ask for help from moderators until you have the rep.

Comment: @Laurence - I can understand how your solution (making it a real SO meta) would solve your immediate problem, but it's a non-trivial task to take this site and divide it into its two proper parts.  Unless it's truly divided up into the engine vs the SO meta, then reputation here does matter separately from SO proper.

Comment: @Pollyanna ~ Whoa, wait, are you suggesting I implement my own `.callVotingRing(this)` ??? Could it be so easy? I would love to have 10k rep on MSO ... perty please

Comment: @Shog9 Sometimes the truth hurts. The fact is people who have high rep on Meta have more control over Stack Overflow than people who have high rep on Stack Overflow. Meta is a disjoint community that has control over another, and Stack Overflow has no autonomous control over things like feature requests. If they want to say "we screwed up, but it's too hard to fix" that'd be easier to buy than all of these rationalizations for why it isn't broken when it clearly is.

Comment: @Laurence, you don't need rep here to help influence Stack Overflow.  It helps with things like editing and tagging, but authoring posts and voting is something you can do from the beginning.

Comment: @Pollyanna Yes, I know it serves a dual purpose. My point is, should it? I don't think it should. Really there should be two sites: meta.stackoverflow.com which is actually the meta for stackoverflow.com and a separate site to act as the "national capital". There's no real reason to have them combined other than historical reasons (ie: it was a mistake, and it's too hard to fix now).

Comment: @Laurence, most of the content from this site would be moved to the new Meta.SE.  There is not much explicit SO content here. (Not trying to make a point here.  Just making an observation)

Comment: @JJnguy As I mentioned in another comment thread: "there are many capabilities that aren't enabled at 100. Voting down, for example, or seeing the up and down vote totals for something. There's also a perceptual handicap in that people more likely to vote up things from someone who already has high rep, while more likely to vote down things from people who have low rep."

Comment: @Laurence: The **fact** is that 40K doesn't give my votes any more weight than those cast by a user with 4K or 400 points. The **fact** is that feature requests by new users do get serious attention. The **fact** is that folks with high rep on Meta generally know how to get their point across without making other users waste *hours* trying to drag it out of them. For someone with 20K on SO, you're remarkably uninformed as to how these sites work.

Comment: @Laurence - "it clearly is [broken]"  - No, it's not clear at all.  You have yet to point out any behavior that could be characterized as broken.  Assuming, for the moment, that "different" means "broken" you still haven't given any evidence as to how this is actively damaging the community and collection of sites.  Please provide evidence that it is broken, and the subsequent symptoms of damage.

Comment: @Laurence, I can't disagree with those facts.  I can only make an observation that I don't think people with low rep are discriminated as much as you might think.  If newbies have good ideas and author good questions or answers, they will receive lots of upvotes. (The same obviously goes for bad posts and downvotes)

Comment: Meta users don't have any extra control over Stack Overflow - some of us who don't use Stack Overflow tend to stay out of things that aren't general engine matters. This is actually the same for the per-site-metas - people can be exceptionally active on the Meta site for helping build the site itself, but have very poor reputation on the corresponding parent site. And all of that exceptional activity actually amounts to very little. People don't make influence by their score - they make an influence by presenting quality ideas.

Comment: @Pollyanna I certainly haven't found it easy to build rep on meta. My point is that I shouldn't have to though. Clearly I'm an active member of the Stack Overflow community, so shouldn't I have the same privileges on Stack Overflow's meta as anyone else?

Comment: @Pollyanna Also, I've not sure why you suggest "flag posts and ask for help from moderators until you have the rep".

Comment: @Laurence You might want to post a different discussion/feature-request question suggesting a method for allowing users more privileges based on their rep on other sites (something using their total SE rep, something using the highest rep they have on a single site, etc.); I think this one is pretty much useless at this point

Comment: @Laurence - the 100 point association bonus gives you all the rep you need to upvote, downvote, and do everything that has significant editorial impact on this site. Everything else is just moderating, which does provide some direction to the discussion, but primarily serves as a filing, sorting, and editing function. Regarding the dual purpose nature of this site, it's probably useful to recognize that this proposal you are making would only be useful on the suggested "national" site, and you still wouldn't have any significant rep.

Comment: @Shog9 That you are not influenced by other people's reps when deciding how to vote for them probably makes you the exception. Certainly on Stack Overflow I have encountered numerous situations where two people have given virtually identical answers and the person with the higher rep has ended up getting more votes despite being the later (again, identical) answer. It isn't extremely common (as identical answers aren't extremely common, to begin with) but it happens.

Comment: @Shog9 My point was made in my original question. The situation with my own reps is merely a datapoint. The real problem is the inconsistency, which hasn't really been addressed, merely rationalized around.

Comment: @Laurence: the mistake you're making is in somehow expecting Meta to work the same way SO does. It doesn't. Voting works differently, discussion happens differently, and of course the sorts of "questions" that are generally asked are completely different. Inconsistency does not, in and of itself, constitute a problem. If that's all you have, then we might as well close this one as a duplicate as well.

Comment: @Pollyanna 100 points is not enough to downvote.

Comment: @Laurence - "I certainly haven't found it easy to build rep on meta." You've only made four posts - how much rep do you think you should have received from two questions and two answers?  "shouldn't I have the same privileges on Stack Overflow's meta as anyone else?" I think you may have run into a chicken and egg problem.  Do you really only intend to participate in meta-so questions, or do you want to help direct the development of the engine?  Your suggestion would give you rep for the former, but not the latter.  There's not a lot to discuss that's strictly meta-SO...

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure what you mean. I understand that Meta doesn't operate the same as Stack Overflow. I know it isn't really (just) a "question an answer" site, for example. If I thought it was I would have phrased the title of this question/feature-request as a question. Why do you think I'm expecting them to work the same way?

Comment: @drachenstern - Your ideas on interior design intrigue me, and I would like a subscription to your newsletter.

Comment: @Pollyanna That's an interesting point, but if there isn't a lot to discuss that's strictly meta-SO wouldn't the same be true of the other sites? If so, then why do Meta Super User and Meta Server Fault exist?

Comment: @Laurence: because you expect high-rep users to get up-voted based on the number next to their name, you expect experience on SO to translate into experience here, and you *don't* seem to expect (or respect) push-back in response to posting a feature-request.

Comment: @Laurence - if you visit the sites you mention, you'll find that there is very little discussion happening.  What is your point?  Homogeneity for Homogeneity's sake is really terrible reasoning to make such a change.  **Show use examples of the bad things that are happening to the community because meta.so is fundamentally different than the other meta sites.**

Comment: @Pollyanna "how much rep do you think you should have received from two questions and two answers?" feels a bit like asking "how did you expect to win the case with such a small bribe for the judge?". I didn't expect to have to earn rep separately. I have few questions to ask on Meta, and I rarely see questions that I'm interested in answering. On a number of occasions I've wanted to participate in voting for a feature request, however, and the inability to downvote is pretty irritating.

Comment: @Shog9 I did expect push-back. What led you to believe otherwise? Also, how have I illustrated lack of respect?

Comment: @Laurence: my very first comment on your previous question stated simply, "after careful study, start a discussion that is both informed by and significantly different from past discussions", and you've since been asked repeatedly, in this increasingly lengthy series of comments, to justify your requests - instead, you've spouted one assertion after another that the system should change purely for consistency's sake and anyone who disagrees is doing so out of a selfish desire to "stick it to" SO users. Believe it or not, we're trying to help you make a better request... You just have to listen

Comment: @Shog9 I apologize if my frustration came through as disrespect: that wasn't intended. I am arguing to try and understand the objections, not to be disrespectful. As far as I can tell I have justified my request several times and in various different ways. I also did read the things you'd linked to, by the way, but they still didn't really explain why there is no separate "real" meta for SO.

Comment: @Laurence: no worries. FWIW, I think your new feature request finally gets at what you've been trying to ask for this whole time, so good work there.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek Good idea. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/feature-request-set-user-privileges-on-meta-stack-overflow-based-on-combined-rep

Comment: This seems like a reasonable point. Things would be more logically organized, more systematic, less confusing for new users, and more well-structured, more  symmetric, and so on if every SE site had a corresponding meta, and there was another meta for the whole network. I can understand that they don't want to do this, but I'm surprised the question has a significant negative score.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: @kiamlaluno This is a possible duplicate of something that was posted more than a year later?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow is getting a Meta of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-meta-of-its-own)

Answer (score 31):

#### Update

As the relevant communities grew, this did start to make sense. And three years later, [we did implement it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014).

---

> How does the fact that Stack Overflow is large justify the lack of a "real" Meta site?

This is a reasonable question. You probably won't like the answer...

SO is large, and SO was first. SO is large in part *because* SO was first, but there are several other factors involved that contribute to its size - suffice to say, it's unlikely any other SE site will achieve anything close to the scale of SO anytime soon.

*Because* SO is large, and *because* SO was first, many issues arise on SO that don't affect the other SE sites at all, only occur on them after they've been active for a significant amount of time, or occur simultaneously but get noticed on SO first. So chances are, if you're encountering a problem on CatFanciers.SE, it's already been encountered, reported, discussed, and perhaps even resolved on SO.

An excellent example of this is [the wiki FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites): this started *on SO*, was migrated to Meta, and then gradually modified and expanded to cover SE as a whole.

Now sure, the SO/SE team could create *another* meta site for SO, move this one to ubermeta.stackexchange.com, and then manually migrate new questions from the SO meta to the global meta when it becomes apparent that they're globally-relevant... But why? What does adding more work solve, apart from consistency *for the sake of consistency*?

There's nothing wrong with consistency. It would probably reduce some small amount of confusion on the part of new users, but whether or not this would make up for the additional confusion of sending users to *yet another meta site* when they have questions is debatable. And most importantly, the current system doesn't require any additional effort - it's already done, paid for long ago, its cost amortized over time. [It's not enough that a feature *could be implemented* - it needs to offer a compelling benefit to offset the cost of implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160229162228/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

There are two primary reasons.

- It's grandfathered in - after several years of this usage it makes little sense to change it out simply because it doesn't match all the other meta sites
- It's the crucible for the Stack Overflow engine itself - Stack Overflow, being the largest and most used site, generates the most usable data regarding the design of the engine used on all the other sites

If you build machines that other people use, then it makes sense to place the corporate offices near the largest user of your machines.

Furthermore, but probably less importantly, the site to which this meta is attached is composed of programmers<sup>*</sup> who are probably well suited to debugging, analyzing, and presenting problems in a manner that the site owners will be able to understand and respond to easily.  If Jeff & Co. were ice skaters, it would probably be better if the crucible site was dedicated to ice skating so problems could be presented within the knowledgespace the site builders are familiar with.

Plus we're curmudgeonly like that.

<sup>*</sup><sub>AI simulants built by Jon Skeet</sub>

Comment: +1 for "Plus we're curmudgeonly like that." :-D

Comment: Please note that I have changed my position on this matter, and am leaving this here only because I can't argue with prior self.  He makes some pretty decent points, even though he's wrongity wrong wrong wrong.

Answer (score 12):

If I understand it correctly, meta.SO is really meta.SE -- it's the meta for all sites. The only reason it's not at meta.SE is that meta.SE already exists -- it's the meta for SE1 sites. Rather than evict the existing meta.SE, they just left meta.SO alone, but it's intended as the meta for all SE-wide issues. The first part of the explanation you posted was a little weak (the part about "Stack Overflow is large enough to justify this"), but the second part explained it well:

> Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.

Comment: You've explained that it's the "National Capital", which I get, but you haven't explained why they don't give SO a real meta and move the "capital" somewhere more sensible.

Comment: @Laurence Because it would be a lot of effort for essentially no gain? I guess if that's your question [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73816/stop-special-casing-stack-overflows-meta/73819#73819) explained it pretty well

Comment: If there's no gain then there would have been no gain in sharing rep on the other sites.

Comment: @Laurence: I don't think you realize the massive difference in size between SO, Meta.SO, and Meta.*random*.SE - Meta is *tiny* compared to SO, just big enough to maintain a community of dedicated users drawn from across all the SE sites. The other metas are much, much smaller, and can't necessarily support a community of users on their own. SO, and *perhaps* SU and SF are large enough that a meta site could garner enough users to work... But without rep-sharing, many of the smaller meta sites would be ghost-towns. It wouldn't hurt Meta.SO, but it isn't *necessary*. minus 100 points...

Answer (score 7):

I don't see how this is any less of a dupe than [your question from half an hour ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73812/isnt-it-about-time-that-meta-stackoverflow-shared-rep-with-its-parent-just-like), but I sympathize with your continuing confusion.

I can answer your "why" question. Look again at [New Per-Site Metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/). It says "**every new website launches with its own dedicated meta site**" right at the top, bold included. The key word there is "new."

MSO launched before any other meta site, and for a time, it was the meta for SO, SF, SU and A51. That made it the *de facto* meta for the Stack Exchange engine by the time the first per-site metas started appearing, and before the SE network even included the original trilogy.

By then, as Michael Mrozek points out, the team just decided the name and old posts were so tangled up that it wasn't worth untangling, and it only gets worse every day.

Comment: So it's worth disentangling programmers.stackexchange and stackoverflow, but not nationa-capital.stackoverflow and meta.stackoverflow?

Comment: @Laurence yes, because programmers.SE was the solution to a year-long ongoing problem.

Comment: @Pekka meta.stackoverflow is a bigger and longer-lasting problem than the non-problem programmers.SE "solved".