# Please set user privileges on Meta Stack Exchange based on combined reputation across sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, meta, privileges

Meta Stack Exchange (formerly Meta Stack Overflow) is really the “National Capital”, as mentioned in this bit from the [New Per-Site Metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) blog post:

> Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.

Given that, instead of setting user privileges solely on Meta Stack Exchange reputation, perhaps there should be a sort of "combined rep" that's used only in computing privileges. This would be similar to the previously-suggested [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su), but limited to The One Meta (as suggested by the jjnguy in a comment on that request).

There are a number of possible "combined rep" formulas that could be used, like max on all sites, or maybe some sort of weighted sum. (Please feel free include ideas for such a function in your answer.) Whatever function is used it's probably best to ensure that it cannot be any lower than the Meta rep so as to ensure that existing Meta users do not lose any privileges.

The goal of this feature request is to enable users of all SE sites to contribute on Meta at a level consistent with their "home" site(s).

Here's an example to make it more clear what I'm talking about:

Let's say the "combined rep" is computed as:

```
 max(meta_rep, max(other_reps) / 2) # strawman combined rep function
```

Suppose we take my existing Stack Overflow and Meta reps, 20615 and 153, respectively. My "combined rep" would be 10307. My rep on Meta would still be (and display as) 153, but I'd be able to do things like show total up and down vote counts or edit tags (two things I cannot do on Meta today) as the "combined rep" would be used for determining privileges.

Comment: You took a long route to get to this actual feature request

Comment: I don't like the idea of showing your rep as 153 even though you have a privilege level of 10,307.  I like the idea of giving meta users higher rep if they have it elsewhere.  But it will get confusing if you don't show it as well.

Comment: @random Not a duplicate. This question (and jjnguy's comment on that question) asks about "merging reps" on the "meta capital." That question asks about "merging reps" on all sites.

Comment: There is some precedence for this in the way the rep bonus for A51 committal is calculated... Might want to consider following that.

Comment: @radp - Are the answers likely to be substantially different?

Comment: @Shog9 Also, on chat.SE privileges are based on combined reputation. If nothing else, the SOIS team _is_ looking into combined-rep-based privs.

Comment: Can we reopen this question? I think this is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Pol: I would hope so. That was a seriously destructive idea (if applied to *all* SE sites)

Comment: @random Thanks... but why close it as a dupe when I went to great pains to make it *not* the same request?

Comment: @radp: there are *privileges* on chat.SE? Since when is fewer beatings considered a privilege?

Comment: @Pollyanna - Yes. Many people feel about MSO rep differently than they do about other sites' rep.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes: creating rooms, creating galleries and reviewing flags. (Oh, and actually talking.)

Comment: @jzd: Yeah, I'm unsure about that myself. Maybe you could show both on Meta, or maybe Meta only shows the "combined" rep (though it would still have its own internal rep value that acts as an input for the combined rep). I am more concerned about having privileges be similar than the number that shows up next to my name.

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't mention using an average because an average is technically just a particular weighted sum, but perhaps it's clearer to mention it explicitly.

Comment: @Laurence: I was mostly interested in explicitly calling out the previous question for purposes of contrast... Still mulling how to better illustrate the differences.

Comment: Closed as dupe because reading it did not show any difference or effort in making it different to the earlier requests about hiding ulterior motives

Comment: @random Several others have pointed out that it *is* different. I'm not sure how you could have actually read what I wrote and thought it was the same. I'm not sure what to make of your "ulterior motives" comment.

Comment: In other news, the layout of the revision history page of this question is busted.

Comment: @Jon: it's the long title - you can see the same happening on other questions where the title wraps to two lines. Fortunately, this one was easy enough to shorten.

Comment: @Shog: Ahhh yes, nice find.

Comment: @Jon it's also been noted and a fix is in the next version of the software to be pushed. Additionally, there are at least three fixes for it.

Comment: Coming to this late, but... another advantage would be that it would discourage rep farming, reducing the amount of noise posts. Would also be more inviting, as new meta users would get a clearer signal that downvotes are disagreement.

Answer (score 10):

<sup>There's a tldr; summary at the bottom for you skimmers, you know who you are...</sup>

There are two types of meta questions:

1. Those that apply primarily to the specific site in question (such as whether a specific question should be closed)
2. Those that apply to the Stack Exchange engine (such as bug reports, feature requests, etc.)

Further, there are several levels of user engagement and abilities.  Once one has sufficient rep in any one community, they are given 100 reputation in other communities, which gives them all the basics, except for downvoting.  It only takes another 25 rep (2.5 post upvotes) to increase one's rep enough to get the ability to downvote.

If Meta.SE were *solely* hosting questions of type 1 above, then I'd have no objection to using some sort of calculation to allow advanced moderating equivalent to some function of the person's rep on the main Q&A sites.

However, I believe there is some value in treating Meta.SE as a separate community with a niche.  Yes, it does serve questions of type 1 to a small degree, but its community *primarily* serves and deals with questions of type 2.  In effect, it is just as much a separate community as the other Q&A sites.

In other words, it has a particular niche audience of experts who have worked with Stack Exchange to some depth and for some period of time, not just as users, but as long-term contributors to the overall direction of the engine development. It's essentially a Q&A site, whose subject happens to be Stack Exchange.

For this reason, there is value in treating it as a separate community with its own, separate reputation system based on questions and answers contained inside it - and not based on questions and answers dealt with in other sites.

The 100 rep bonus given just by having some experience with some other Stack Exchange site is enough to get most people most of the access they need.  (The reputation requirement for downvoting is also reduced on this site, so the bonus will also grant that here.) Higher privileges beyond that should be earned, just as they should be earned if moving from Stack Overflow with 20k rep to a non-tech site.

If one wants to attain more privileges than those, simply answering one or two questions a day on here will yield enough reputation to attain whatever level one wants.

I'm not convinced that having 20k reputation on, for instance, the Electrical Engineering site should give one the ability to vote to close questions here, without at least engaging with the existing meta community for a short period of time.  But it does gives the basic abilities to ask questions, answer questions, comment, flag, vote, and edit community wiki posts.

And as useful as editing, closing, and deleting are, the best way to help move the community in any particular direction is using words - so the first and foremost feature, that of asking and answering questions, is always available.

### tl;dr:

It's a niche site, just like Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, etc.  While it's called "Meta", the reality is that it is a community of experts (not just users, but experts and wallowers in the mud) in one niche, and the reputation system is and should be separate from the other sites, especially given that the 100 rep bonus for account association provides nearly everything one needs anyway.

Answer (score 2):

1. Maybe I'm the only one, but my feeling is that meta reputation *is* different to reputation on SO or other SE sites. It's just *not that serious*. While I take pride in my (limited, but respectable) SO rep, my meta rep is a bit of a joke (especially as you can get quite a lot of rep *from* jokes!).
2. Also, on meta, downvotes indicate disagreement, not that you are necessarily wrong.
3. I'm not sure, but my feeling is that SO rep is worth 'less' than rep on other sites - simply by the fact that the combined 'wealth' of SO users completely dwarfs that of other sites

These three elements combined lead me to the conclusion that unifying (or even comparing) the 'currencies' of these different sites just because the currency has the same name (reputation) is not a good idea.

Comment: Your first two points may, in fact, be good arguments to get rid of meta rep and base one's abilities on the rep they've attained at other sites...

Comment: I agree with this; The ability to retag, for example, shouldn't be based on whether or not people agree with meta posts. Maybe a 2-tier rep system on meta would be better, one for I agree/disagree, and one for 'You make raise a good point'.