# Should stack overflow sites share base rep(100) to some degree?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stack-exchange

Example, user123 has 10k rep on Stack Overflow, but zero on Home Improvement.  Should user123 be given the same rights as user321 who just registered on their first Stack Overflow site minutes ago?  Or should they be given 100 rep instantly based on prior experience, so they can do things such as post images, comment anywhere, etc?

Similar: [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/please-set-user-privileges-on-meta-stack-overflow-based-on-combined-rep-across-si)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think it's a good idea to give 100 bonus reputation when a new account is linked to one with high reputation on another site.

In fact, this [already happens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#login). (Link is to Meta's FAQ, not DIY's. For some reason, this is the only one that mentions the bonus.)

Comment: Are you saying that this already is in place?

Comment: @dpollitt: Yes, sorry, was hunting up a suitable reference.

Comment: I have 428rep in the Photography site, so why do I only have 6 here?  Shouldn't I have 101+?

Comment: @dpollitt: Your [associations tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161501/dpollitt?tab=accounts) doesn't show anything for me. Can you dissassociate all your accounts and re-asssociate them?

Comment: I disassociated all and readded, fixed!  I have 113 rep here now.  Not sure if it was a bug, or what exactly happened, but that did the trick.