# Should a score on one Stack Exchange site "help" a user on other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I did very well on some Stack Exchange sites, like Stack Overflow. So I got good scores on some Stack Exchange sites, but I can't ask any more questions on the others. That seems permanent.

Just letting people keep asking bad questions is a bad idea. However, locking someone out of asking questions permanently maybe too harsh. What about if the person just need to get used to it? What about if his/her questions on another part of Stack Exchange is fine?

I suggest that users can have their sin purged in one Stack Exchange site say at the cost of 500-1000 points on another Stack Exchange site. That's a hefty price. They'll get better.

Comment: Moderators can't impose question bans.

Comment: A question ban is never 'permanent': You get a chance to ask a good question every 6 months. Question bans are there to slow down users, not to completely block them. So there's still a chance to get used to a different site, both before and after you were question banned.

Comment: Have you read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/273494)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please set user privileges on Meta Stack Exchange based on combined reputation across sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73848/282094) -  ability, reputation, experience, etc. on one or more sites doesn't translate across the board for ability on every site. Some people only do well on one or two sites and perform poorly on multiple other ones; it wouldn't be fair to unban them where they caused a problem for good efforts elsewhere - that would make such measures very weak.

Answer (score 14):

I've got 100K on 2 sites - MSE and Super User. That literally does not mean that I know *anything* about programming. As an experienced SE user, I have no illusions that having high rep on one site means that I am any good in another.

> Just letting people keep asking bad questions is a bad idea.

We agree there

> However, locking someone out of asking questions permanently maybe too harsh.

We don't, you get an opportunity to ask questions every 6 months and if you can contribute positively in other ways, and *demonstrate* you know the site - with *good* answers and suggested edits, you might be able to get out.

> What about if the person just need to get used to it? What about if his questions in other part of stackexchange is fine.

My reputation shows I know the 'basics' of SE. It does not reflect any competency beyond that or competence of some sort in the subject matter of the specific site.

> I suggest that users can have their sin purge in one stackexchange say at the cost of 500-1000 points in other stackexchange. That's hefty price. They'll get better.

That's.... maybe a good month's worth of rep for me. And I could pretty much *mint* get out of question ban cards anywhere. The end result of this though is  people will go site shopping *mainly* for reputation, get frustrated, and also frustrate users there.

Comment: This one says that question ban is permanent https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th Also because a user is banned he cannot contribute anything

Comment: Question bans and answer bans are seperate, And reputation is *one* component of a question ban. You don't have to 'just' ask questions after all.The opportunity to ask questions every 6 months is a thing, though why its not documented, I have no idea. That said, rather than worrying about not being able to ask questions - one might want to focus also on finding answers and other aspects of the site too

Comment: Oh so question ban expire after 6 months?

Comment: You get one opportunity to ask a question every 6 months. If you can make it count, it would likely improve your possibility of getting out of the ban for good