# Will Meta rep be joined with SO rep?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I'm happy that finally SO will get its own Meta, and it will make quite a few things a ***lot*** easier. One thing that I'm wondering about is reputation. Specifically, will my reputation from Meta get added into my reputation on SO? It would make sense because the reputation is still earned, and asking good questions and providing good answers on Meta *would* improve your real reputation. Though it doesn't show that you have programming skills. This is not all what reputation is about though. From the FAQ:

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts
>   you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re
>   talking about.

This statement says that reputation is how much the community trusts you, so it would make sense to join the two reputations. The next sentence—"it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you're talking about"—doesn't support the idea of joining the rep. Most posts on Meta are complaining posts. Complaining doesn't show that you know how to program.

Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: This _is_ the SO meta site. What do you mean that SO will get its own meta?

Comment: You would no longer have *any* reputation on Meta.SO. It would just display your reputation from the main site, which would be unaffected by votes on your meta posts.

Comment: @Oded [You missed the big news. Meta.SO is going to be split out from Meta.SE like the other metas on the network.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - What can I say, I live under a rock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's looking like your existing Meta Stack Overflow rep will become your Meta Stack Exchange rep (minus any posts clean up or migrated to the new meta.stackoverflow).

Comment: Heh. I will suddenly become a trusted user on Meta.